# How to do navigation from pages to pages in WPF in MVVM pattern ? without the concept of prism

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

Currently iam developing a wpf application that have so many pages.
So i created it like a single main window and according to the button or menu item click navigating pages into a frame.
Iam pretty new at Wpf and even iam creating it in MVVM.

Navigation through PRISM is complicated for me. i have found so many articles , but most of them not for freshers in wpf.
So how we can easily done it in MVVM? anyone have simple demo?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few options here, one which I use is developing your application as a **SPA** (Single page application). Essentially, you will have **one master window**, which will hold a `ContentControl` bound to the current View Model.

This [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/72724/Beginning-a-WPF-MVVM-application-Navigating-betwee) seems to follow this idea rather well. Also, [this](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/) should help.

If you need to create new windows then you should look into creating a window navigation **service** which can be injected into your View Models using **dependency injection**. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj694937.aspx) should help you further.